# Neon and arm assembly optimization

Tags: assembly, arm, neon

I'm implementing in Neon and arm assembly a computer vision **convolution** algorithm where each pixel is replaced by the sum-product of the nine self and adjacent pixels. The main loop looks like this:

```
.loop:
    vld1.u8 {d0}, [line_prev]
    add line_prev, line_prev, #1
    vld1.u8 {d1}, [line_prev]
    add line_prev, line_prev, #1
    vld1.u8 {d2}, [line_prev]
    add line_prev, line_prev, #6

    vld1.u8 {d3}, [line]
    add line, line, #1
    vld1.u8 {d4}, [line]
    add line, line, #1
    vld1.u8 {d5}, [line]
    add line, line, #6

    vld1.u8 {d6}, [line_next]
    add line_next, line_next, #1
    vld1.u8 {d7}, [line_next]
    add line_next, line_next, #1
    vld1.u8 {d8}, [line_next]
    add line_next, line_next, #6

//Everything is loaded now. Let's multiply and sum

    vmull.u8 q10, d0, d10       //d10 to d18 holds the kernel matrix values
    vmlal.u8 q10, d1, d11
    vmlal.u8 q10, d2, d12
    vmlal.u8 q10, d3, d13
    vmlal.u8 q10, d4, d14
    vmlal.u8 q10, d5, d15
    vmlal.u8 q10, d6, d16
    vmlal.u8 q10, d7, d17
    vmlal.u8 q10, d8, d18
    vshrn.u16 d4, q10, d19      //Shift the sum by the value in d19

    vst1.u8 {d4}, [out]!        //Store result

    subs temp, temp, #8     //We have processed 8 pixels
    bgt .loop
```

How can I optimize (in terms of speed) this loop? Is there anything smarter to do to load the pixels. Also, q11... are available: should I use them to have the vmull and mlal instructions in parallel?

Comment: If you're targetting a specific CPU, one thing to investigate is prefetching. Manually inserting prefetch instructions can speed things up, but only for a given cache size and code disposition. If your program is portable to different Cortex models, forget about manual prefetch unless you want to maintain conditionally compiled code for each one.

Comment: I'm targeting a specific ARM, aka. OMAP4 dual cortex-A9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the same data 3 times per line is almost certainly worth avoiding if at all possible. Unaligned loads in general might be harder to avoid if the data is not amenably-sized, but [will cost an extra cycle](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0409e/BCGGIDBH.html), which is worth bearing in mind.

An approach I'd try is to keep two registers' worth of data on the go for a line, and use [`vext`](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0473l/dom1361289953622.html) to pull the offset data out of the pair, saving two loads and a few cycles per iteration at the cost of one extra register, something like:

```
    vld1.u8 {d0}, [line]!  ; 'initial' chunk
    ...
.loop:
    vld1.u8 {d3}, [line]!  ; 'next' chunk
    ...
    vext.8  d1, d0, d3, #1
    vext.8  d2, d0, d3, #2

    ; do stuff with d0=line, d1=line+1, d2=line+2
    ...
    vmov    d0, d3  ; 'next' chunk becomes 'current' chunk for the next iteration
    ...
    bgt .loop
```

As mentioned by others, if you are happy to target a specific microarchitecture then carefully-tuned manual preloading can be highly beneficial for older cores. Off the top of my head, I think the sweet spot for Cortex-A9 tends to be 2 cache lines ahead. Note that it might only be necessary to prefetch ahead of `line_next` if the images are small enough compared to your L1 cache that the preceding lines stay hot.

Answer (score 5):

Try interleaving the load code and the maths code. You want to some load/use delay (aim for a couple of cycles), but interleaved loads and maths generally works better.

Loading Q registers to fetch 16 values at a time may help, rather than D registers, if you can work the register space to fit it all in. Streaming load/use as per the above helps (you can often use one physical register for two values in a single iteration).

Use preload.